# I am React beginner,User login Verification

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am doing a login page using react. 
I have tried BrowserRouter, Switch , Link.

I am trying to figure out how to apply the function of link to bring webpage to the next page but require the correct email address and password.

I know normal button function that switch to the next page can be done by using link directly, but when using the concept on the login button, I start to confuse.

Comment: You need to have login component which will validate your email and password, based on the result either redirect(use <Redirect />) or show error on same page .go through the articles present on react login validation for detail

Comment: You can also use history.push() https://www.npmjs.com/package/history to navigate